# how to execute method of action class without refreshing the page in struts2

Tags: struts2

i am developing an application using struts2. i have a button in a JSP page, which executes an action method upon its click. i want to execute this action method but without refreshing the page. is there any way i can accomplish that? what the action does is that is sets a value of an integer and i just have to display it on the page.

my method:

```
public void setVariable(){
    //Code to get a random integer
    return "SUCCESS";
}
```

jsp page code for form:

```
<form method="post" action="setVariable">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly Understands you.

In your struts.xml

```
<action name="yourAction" class="ActionClass" >
   <result name="success" type="httpheader" >
      <param name="status">202</param> 
          </result>
 </action>
```

Turn your `Action response` as `httpheader` and this will reflect no page refresh i.e response will come to the same JSP page and you can print the variable that you set in the `Action class` using `setter` of that variable.

And in your JSP handle the codes based on the result

as

```
 $.ajax({

     statusCode:{202:function()
                {
           alert("result was success");
                  }}
             });
```

I am not very much sure with the syntax of the Ajax code in JSP. try to do in this way.

Comment: i tried doing it. it just gives me a blank page. i tried using both GET and POST methods, to the same result

Comment: also, i am trying to read the value of the variable using <s:property>

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try to do that with Ajax ? You can execute an action, manipulate data and then get the result in JSP ?

In JSP:

```
function javascript_function(inputIfAny)
{
    $.getJSON("<s:property value='%{ajaxCallUrl}' />",
        { value: value},
            function(data)
            {
                dataAttributeValue = data.valueToSendToJSP; // If needed
            });

}

<s:url id="ajaxCallUrl" action="actionName" method="ajaxMethod" />
```

And in your Struts 2 action:

```
public void ajaxAccountUpdateHandle()
{
    Map<String, Object> params = ActionContext.getContext().getParameters();
    String value = params.get("numAcn");
    try
    {
        JsonFactory f = new JsonFactory();
        JsonGenerator generator = f.createJsonGenerator(response.getOutputStream());

        // Do stuff
        generator.writeStartObject();
        generator.writeStringField("valueToSendToJSP", "foo");
        generator.writeEndObject();
        generator.flush();
        generator.close();
    }
    catch (JsonGenerationException e)
    {
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
}
```

This way, you won't even need an entry in the struts XML.

Comment: What do you mean with that: *you won't even need an entry in the struts XML*? Instead of using `<s:property>` you can use `<s:url>` directly w/o the `id` attribute, which is deprecated BTW.